# how to copy an array into a bigger array(partial copy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to copy an array into another.

```
a = np.array([1]*3)
b = np.array([2]*2)
```

I tried `copyto()`

```
np.copyto(a,b)
```

But I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>   
>       np.copyto(a,b) ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (3)

How can I get `a` to become equal to [2,2,1] ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign the values in `b` to a slice of `a`:

```
In [16]: a[:len(b)] = b

In [17]: a
Out[17]: array([2, 2, 1])
```

Comment: I'm too slow on the draw :)

Comment: Also, note that the nD version is a bit more unwieldy.  `a[tuple([slice(0, n) for n in b.shape])] = b` for the fully-general case.

Comment: @maazza: `np.copyto` tries to broadcast `b` up to the shape of `a`. Since an array of shape (2,) can't be broadcast to an array of shape (3,), it raises an ValueError. Since a basic slice is a view, `np.copyto(a[:len(b)], b)`  also works.